# Nested, Same-Level For Loop, Output to List

Tags: python, list, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I am having trouble appending data into a list as I iterate through the following:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas

def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    thepage.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, 'html.parser')
    return soupdata

soup = make_soup('https://www.wellstar.org/locations/pages/default.aspx')

locationdata = []

for table in soup.findAll('table', class_ = 's4-wpTopTable'):
   for name in table.findAll('div', 'PurpleBackgroundHeading'):
       name = name.get_text(strip = True)
   for loc_type in table.findAll('h3', class_ = 'WebFont SpotBodyGreen'):
       loc_type = loc_type.get_text()
   for address in table.findAll('div', class_ = ['WS_Location_Address', 'WS_Location_Adddress']):
       address = address.get_text(strip = True, separator = ' ')
       locationdata.append([name, loc_type, address])

df = pandas.DataFrame(columns = ['name', 'loc_type', 'address'], data = locationdata)
print(df)
```

The produced dataframe includes all unique addresses, however only the last possible text corresponding to the `name`.

For example, even though 'WellStar Windy Hill Hospital' is the last hospital within the hospital category/type, it appears as the name for all hospitals.  If possible, I prefer a `list.append` solution as I have several more, similar steps to go through to finalize this project.

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring because you're looping through all the names and loc_types *before* you're appending to `locationdata`.

You can instead do:

```
import itertools as it
from pprint import pprint as pp

for table in soup.findAll('table', class_='s4-wpTopTable'):
  names = [name.get_text(strip=True) for 
           name in table.findAll('div', 'PurpleBackgroundHeading')]
  loc_types = [loc_type.get_text() for 
               loc_type in table.findAll('h3', class_='WebFont SpotBodyGreen')]
  addresses = [address.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for 
               address in table.findAll('div', class_=['WS_Location_Address',  
                                                       'WS_Location_Adddress'])]

for name, loc_type, address in it.izip_longest(names,loc_types,addresses):
  locationdata.append([name, loc_type, address])
```

Result:

```
>>> pp.pprint(locationdata)
[[u'WellStar Urgent Care in Acworth',
  u'WellStar Urgent Care Centers',
  u'4550 Cobb Parkway NW Suite 101 Acworth, GA 30101 770-917-8140'],
 [u'WellStar Urgent Care in Kennesaw',
  None,
  u'3805 Cherokee Street Kennesaw, GA 30144 770-426-5665'],
 [u'WellStar Urgent Care in Marietta - Delk Road',
  None,
  u'2890 Delk Road Marietta, GA 30067 770-955-8620'],
 [u'WellStar Urgent Care in Marietta - East Cobb',
  None,
  u'3747 Roswell Road Ne Suite 107 Marietta, GA 30062 470-956-0150'],
 [u'WellStar Urgent Care in Marietta - Kennestone',
  None,
  u'818 Church Street Suite 100 Marietta, GA 30060 770-590-4190'],
 [u'WellStar Urgent Care in Marietta - Sandy Plains Road',
  None,
  u'3600 Sandy Plains Road Marietta, GA 30066 770-977-4547'],
 [u'WellStar Urgent Care in Smyrna',
  None,
  u'4480 North Cooper Lake Road SE Suite 100 Smryna, GA 30082 770-333-1300'],
 [u'WellStar Urgent Care in Woodstock',
  None,
  u'120 Stonebridge Parkway Suite 310 Woodstock, GA 30189 678-494-2500']]
```

Comment: I feel like this is close, however, the desired result should include the loc_type for each location, address combination.  How can we go about including that information per record?

Comment: I gave you the steps to put your data into a list but you have to make sure you're pulling the right data from the page.